# Multi line TextView edge fading

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, fade

I have a long text with multiple lines. I want to wrap the `TextView` inside the `ScrollView` such that the edge of `ScrollView` apply a **TEMPORARY** alpha gradient `TextView` as the user scroll the text. The fading does not appear at all.

I intentionally set a high value for height of `TextView` but it doesn't work yet neither with this or `WRAP_CONTENT` or even `MATCH_PARENT`.

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="200dp">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:text="He has been involved with various online encyclopedia projects.[7]\nHe is the former editor-in-chief of Nupedia,[8] chief organizer (2001–02) of its successor, Wikipedia,[9] and founding editor-in-chief of Citizendium.[10]\nFrom his position at Nupedia, he assembled the process for article development.[11] Sanger proposed implementing a wiki, which led directly to the creation of Wikipedia.[12]\nInitially Wikipedia was a complementary project for Nupedia.[12]"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</ScrollView>
```

All I could achieve was to remove the `ScrollView` and obtain a **permanent** alpha gradient on `TextView`

[image]

Comment: Change the height of TextView to wrap_content

Comment: In what way does it not work as expected? Does it not scroll?

Comment: @RGraham, It scrolls but there's no fading.